# Change background color of Android Action Bar

Tags: android

I have an Activity with an action bar. minSdkVersion is 11.

The action bar is a grey color, I would like to change it to a different color so that it matches other colors in my application.

I have created the following styles

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

And set this activity's theme in the appmanifest to MyTheme but when I run the application I get this error:

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html, specifically these parts

> Note: If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar,
> then you must use (or override) the Theme.AppCompat family of styles
> (rather than the Theme.Holo family, available in API level 11 and
> higher)

and

> When using the Support Library, you must instead use the Theme.AppCompat themes:
>
> Theme.AppCompat for the "dark" theme.
> Theme.AppCompat.Light for the "light" theme.
> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for the light theme
> with a dark action bar.

Basically you have to replace 'Holo' with 'AppCompat'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), you need to use an AppCompat theme, which brings the Lollipop style Action Bars to all devices and support for the [Material Color Palette](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) allowing you to write a theme such as

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="ColorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

to style your action bar color automatically.

If you'd prefer to not use any of that (and look very different on Lollipop devices), you can instead extend [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) or [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), depending on if you want to use the support library fragments (which backport and fix a number of issues around nested fragments and state saving).

Answer (score 0):

Just use this, if your extending ActivityActionBar on your activity then you need to use the AppCompat themes.

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="ColorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

or use style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark for white text :)

Comment: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: Are you extending ActionBarActivity on your activity?

Comment: Yes I am doing what you said

Comment: Try this <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: Error:(18, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ColorPrimary'.

Comment: <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarColor</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarColor</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarColor" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>

</style>

Comment: Try this ^, might not be working because colorPrimary works on API 21+ only i believe